# Formatting a NSNumber as percentage (%) with one decimal place using NSNumberFormatter

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsnumber

I am trying to format a NSNumber containing a value of 0.305 as "30.5%".

However, my following code does not work:

```
[numberFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterPercentStyle];
[numberFormatter setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
```

How can I specify that the number should be formatted as percentage with one decimal place?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Edited for the actual correct answer:

```
[numberFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterPercentStyle];
[numberFormatter setMinimumFractionDigits:1];
```

Comment: This answer does not take localization in account.

Answer (score 14):

This works for me:

```
[numberFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterPercentStyle];
[numberFormatter setMinimumFractionDigits:1];
```

Comment: this should be the correct answer, as it takes localization into account.

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
float percent = 0.305;

NSString *formattedPercentText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.1f%%", percent * 100];
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using also **setMaximum**

```
float precent = 3.5;

    NSNumberFormatter * numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc]init];
    [numberFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterPercentStyle];     
    [numberFormatter setMinimumFractionDigits:1];
    [numberFormatter setMaximumFractionDigits:1];       
    return [numberFormatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:precent]];
```